# ¿Como puedo borrar registros que se presentan una n cantidad de veces en un dataframe y son str?

Tags: python

estoy intentando borrar registros que aparecen menos de 10 veces en mi dataframe. Especificamente, quiero borrar aquellas filas con localidades que tienen menos de 10 registros, pero al estar en formato de str no se bien como hacerlo. Intenté con un value_counts pero despues no puedo asociarlo con los indices. les muestro mi dataframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) puedes hacerlo fácilmente usando la función `groupby` de la siguiente forma:

```
# asumiendo que tu dataframe se llama df
df_filtrado = df.groupby("localidad").filter(lambda g: (g.count() > 10).all())
```

Esto lo que hará, será agrupar tus datapoints por la columna "localidad" y luego aplicar la función lambda que devuelve los grupos con más de 10 filas...

¡Espero que te sirva!

Comment: gracias Santiago, sos un crack!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo usando el paquete `dplyr`. `add_count()` añade la columna `n` a tu data e indica cuántas observaciones de esa localidad existe en el set de datos. Luego de eso puedes filtrar sólo aquellas que tienen 10 o más observaciones. Finalmente, seleccionar todas las columnas con excepción de `n` porque ya no la necesitas.

```r
library(dplyr)

datos %>% 
  add_count(localidad) %>% 
  filter(n >= 10) %>% 
  select(-n)
```